# Align and subtract similar signals

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have two signals (T0 and T1) and want to subtract them from each other:
[image: T0 and T1]

Essentially, the red graph contains a new signal (the spike on the left) and I want to get this signal by subtracting the blue graph from the red graph.
This code using cross-correlation works for me nearly every time, except in this example:

```
% find cross-correlation
[acor,lag] = xcorr(T1,T0);
[~,I] = max(abs(acor));
lagDiff = lag(I);
% shift T0 to T1
T0_shifted = circshift(T0,lagDiff);

% stretch T0, so that it meets the height of T1
T0_shifted = T0_shifted * max(T1)/max(T0_shifted);
```

The signal is shifted to the unwanted position, because xcorr() returns a maximum at the correct, but unwanted position:

[image: unwanted shift]

Are there any ways to 'tweak' xcorr() or any alternative methods for aligning graphs?

Comment: Please include the signals in your code, otherwise it is impossible for anyone to try alterantives.

Comment: Well, I can't really come up with a minimum working example, but here's the real data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hAp5cbAojyeZQbG_ZXMaoCUdfrqjTvzI

Comment: Why is that 2nd example wrong? What did you expect? As I see it, there are two possible fits, this one has a larger cross-correlation than the other one. Maybe if you scaled the blue signal it would have a better fit over the latter two peaks?

Comment: Of course it is not 'wrong'. It has clearly the larger cross-correlation, but it is not the output I desire. Hence, I am looking for other approaches to align the signals.

Answer (score 0):

My answers are assuming that positioning and/or height has a lot to do with your ideal fit, hopefully this gives you some new ideas.

I would suggest that you look at the `acor` output signal and find the peak instances above some threshold and doing a bit of similar height detection on the shifted signals around those peaks instead of just going with the absolute max. Something like this:

```
[acor, lag] = xcorr(T1, T0);
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(acor);

dHeights = zeros(1, length(locs));
for i = 1:length(locs)
    T0_shifted = circshift(T0, lag(locs(i)));

    % Sum of absolute differences on the entire signal might be good enough
    dHeights = sum(abs(T0_shifted - T1));
end

% Index of minimum value in dHeights corresponds to indexing in pks and locs
[~, I] = min(dHeights);
% To find the actual lag value, find the location of the acor value matching the pks value
lagDiff = lag(acor == pks(I)));
```

If positioning is all you care about, you can also specify an allowable range of lags in `xcorr` by doing something like:

```
trLags = 20; % Limits lag range to [-20, 20]
[acor,lag] = xcorr(T1,trLags);
```

On another note, I notice that you're considering significant negative correlation by doing max(acor) which would match concave and convex spikes that are mirror images of each other - I believe this is *not* what you want.